# Is reporting or querying a bug in a platform (e.g .Net) a valid use of SO?

Tags: discussion

I have found a bug in Asp.Net (won't detail it here, it'll go in an SO question depending on the community response here) and want to share it; as well as hopefully get it in front of the framework team.

I've used MS Connect with reasonable success in the past (and will probably push it there if subsequently the community can reproduce), but that doesn't necessarily help the community that much as connect bugs don't often appear in search engine results (not SEO friendly I think!).

So I figured that SO would be a good platform to peer-review the bug before taking the time to report to MS, as well as to put it front of other developers who might come across the same problem - since SO has v.good SEO (argh so many acronyms!).

This question is also valid for other platforms, of course, it's just that .Net is 'my' platform in this case.

Is this a valid use of SO - or should I go straight to the source?  Does it depend on whether the platform in question has an established forum for such things?  Where do you draw the line?  Third-party or open-source frameworks?  Does it depend on ubiquity - i.e. how widely it's used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If it's definitely a bug, you should report it at the source.
2. If you're not sure it's a bug then ask on Stack Overflow, "I'm seeing this behaviour, is that a bug or am I missing something?"
3. If it's a bug and you're looking for a workaround, ask on Stack Overflow.
4. If it's a bug and you've *found* a workaround, and other people might profit from knowing it, play Jeopardy on Stack Overflow (just like 3., but you answer it yourself).

Answer (score 3):

Well, if I'm stuck with something, my first reaction will be to look it up on StackOverflow.

If I come upon your question, with an answer saying "it's a bug in the platform, here's the MS Connect reference", then that's great as far as I'm concerned.

But for this to be useful, your question needs to be expressed in terms of the symptoms, not in terms of the root cause, or your analysis - I'd stick that in an answer. ([Answering your own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/) is perfectly valid).

Answer (score 1):

If you've identified something and you believe it is a bug in the framework, you should absolutely put it up on MS Connect. Even if it should turn out that it is not a bug in the framework, it is the job of the people there to deal with issues like that, and the forum *exists* for the purpose of reporting these issues.

Submitting it to StackOverflow would not accomplish anything, assuming that the bug is relatively deep in the framework and it would take quite a bit of code and explanation in order to make it reproducible by anyone else.

StackOverflow would be the place to ask for help on a bug that you *don't* think is a framework issue.